# Does the standard Grothendieck topology on topological spaces, push down to the homotopy category?

Tags: homotopy-theory, grothendieck-topologies

Let $C$ be any class of topological spaces, such that for any $X \in C$, if $U$ is a topological space homeomorphic to an open subset of $X$, then $U \in C$.

From now on we view $C$ as a full subcategory of the category of topological spaces.

Let $\mathrm{h}C$, the homotopy category of $C$, denote the category obtained by identifying arrows in $C$ which are parallel (same source and target) and homotopic (as continuous maps).

Let $\tau$ be the standard Grothendieck topology on $C$, generated from the Grothendieck pretopology whose covering families into $X$ are those collections $\{U_i \rightarrow X\}$ of maps which are each open embeddings and whose images cover $X$. (If I'm not mistaken, this is a Grothendieck pretopology?)

My question is, does $\tau$ "push down" to a Grothendieck topology on $\mathrm{h}C$? What would be the best way to show this?

Comment: What do you mean by "push down"? What properties would you like it to have? (I guess that the answer is no, in any case.)

Comment: @ZhenLin I'd eventually like to consider $(\infty,1)$-sheaves on Spaces, where the latter is a convenient category of topological spaces with an appropriate site structure. I'm not sure what is the appropriate $(\infty,1)$-Grothendieck topology on Spaces, but according to the Observation at the nLab page for $(\infty,1)$-site, such topologies are in natural bijection with the Grothendieck topologies on the homotopy category hSpaces. I was wondering if there is a Grothendieck topology on hSpaces which corresponds "most closely" to the usual one on Spaces.

Comment: That is still vague. Anyway, to give some indication why it is unlikely to come to anything interesting: every continuous map can be factored as an injective homotopy equivalence followed by an open embedding followed by a surjective homotopy equivalence, so the concepts of "open embedding" and "surjection" are very very very far from being homotopy-invariant.

Comment: @ZhenLin I see. May I ask, is there any "canonical" choice of $(\infty,1)$-site structure on Spaces, or on SmoothMflds? I am reading the book Differential Cohomology by Amabel et al., and in  section 3.1 the authors seem to be using some $(\infty,1)$-site structure on Mfld which is obtained from the usual 1-site structure on Mfld as a 1-category, but they don't mention how this is obtained.